# В чём проблема с объединением картинок?

Tags: python, изображения, pil

Есть список путей к картинкам, мне нужно их объединить, но проблема в том, что у них может быть разная ширина. Пытаюсь привести к одной, но что-то не робить. В чем может быть проблема?

```
    imgs = []
    whith = sorted([(np.sum(i.size), i.size) for i in [PIL.Image.open(i) for i in list_im]])[0][1][0]
    for x in list_im:
        xx = PIL.Image.open(x)
        width_percent = (whith / float(xx.size[0]))
        height_size = int((float(xx.size[1]) * float(width_percent)))
        new_image = xx.resize((whith, height_size))
        imgs.append(new_image)

    imgs_comb = np.vstack(tuple(np.asarray(i) for i in imgs))
    imgs_comb = PIL.Image.fromarray(imgs_comb)
```

Вот ошибка:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 2, the array at index 0 has size 3 and the array at index 9 has size 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка указывает вам на то, что все изображения в `imgs` должны быть одного размера, а вы делаете `.resize` изображения относительно себя самого. Соответственно, соотношение сторон остается тем же.

Самым простым способом будет сделать `.resize` по размеру наименьшего изображения.

Comment: Нет, проблема была в "RGB" и "RGBA" форматах. Но спасибо за ответ